# Using nested for loop in BASH to run 2x3x6 variable loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, nested-loops

I would like to run a command on my data that registers 3 regions of interest (ROI) within 2 hemispheres and names each output appropriately. I am having trouble figuring out how to keep one line of command within a nested loop, instead of breaking down the loop into several specific ROI loops.

In general, something like this:

```
for a in Right_hemi Left_hemi; do
    for b in ROI1 ROI2 ROI3; do
        for file in ${file1_LEFT} ${file2_LEFT} ${file3_LEFT} ${file1_RIGHT} ${file2_RIGHT} ${file3_RIGHT}; do

            antsApplyTransforms -d 3 -i $file  ${dir_out}/warped_atlas/${a}_${b}_${subject}.nii.gz 

            echo "${a}_${b}_${subject}.nii.gz"

        done
    done
done
```

`$file` is a variable of the actual image used in the code

- example of `$file1_LEFT` variable: `/path/to/variable/file1_LEFT.nii.gz`

`$a` is a naming variable (right/left)

`$b` is a naming variable for `$file`, since I cannot use a file path/name

For clarity, in `$b`:

- ROI1 represents `file1_LEFT` and `file1_RIGHT`
- ROI2 represents `file2_LEFT` and `file2_RIGHT`
- ROI3 represents `file3_LEFT` and `file3_RIGHT`

So the command within the loop will call on `$file` variables but because I cannot use a file for a name, I created `$b` variable strictly for naming purposes. However, this will not work as I will not be able to separate ROIs without mixing them with all files, for example, I cannot have an output combining `ROI1_file2` or `ROI1_file3`. Each `$b` name must match the appropriate `$file` variable so the outputs should be:

```
Left_hemi_ROI1*.gz  # where ROI1 represents file1_LEFT
Right_hemi_ROI1*.gz # where ROI1 represents file1_RIGHT
Left_hemi_ROI2*.gz  # where ROI2 represents file2_LEFT
Right_hemi_ROI2*.gz # where ROI2 represents file2_RIGHT
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another potential solution is to load your "ROI's" into an array and cycle through them, e.g.

```
c=('${ROI1_LEFT}' '${ROI2_LEFT}' '${ROI3_LEFT}' '${ROI1_RIGHT}' '${ROI2_RIGHT}' '${ROI3_RIGHT}')

i=0
for f in Left_hemi Right_hemi
do
    for g in ROI{1..3}
    do
        echo "${f}_${g}_${c[i]}_subject.gz"
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
    done
done
Left_hemi_ROI1_${ROI1_LEFT}_subject.gz
Left_hemi_ROI2_${ROI2_LEFT}_subject.gz
Left_hemi_ROI3_${ROI3_LEFT}_subject.gz
Right_hemi_ROI1_${ROI1_RIGHT}_subject.gz
Right_hemi_ROI2_${ROI2_RIGHT}_subject.gz
Right_hemi_ROI3_${ROI3_RIGHT}_subject.gz
```

So, my guess as to how you could apply this to your actual data is:

```
c=(${ROI1_LEFT} ${ROI2_LEFT} ${ROI3_LEFT} ${ROI1_RIGHT} ${ROI2_RIGHT} ${ROI3_RIGHT})

for subject in subjects
do
    i=0
    for f in Left_hemi Right_hemi
    do
        for g in ROI{1..3}
        do
            antsApplyTransforms -d 3 -i ${c[i]} -r ${dir_out}/FA_${subject}.nii.gz -o ${dir_out}/warped_atlas/"${f}_${g}_${c[i]}_${subject}.nii.gz" 
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: This is close to what I am seeking, I was unclear in my original post and have updated to further explain

Comment: This works if I make two loops one for right and left hemi

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
for a in Right_hemi Left_hemi; do
    a2=${a%_*}                          # remove underscore and following characters
    for b in ROI1 ROI2 ROI3; do
        varname="${b}_${a2^^}"          # concatenate $b, "_", and uppercased "$a2"
        ROI=${!varname}                 # indirect variable reference
            antsApplyTransforms -d 3 -i "$ROI" -r "${dir_out}/FA_${subject}".nii.gz -o "${dir_out}/warped_atlas/${a}_${b}_${subject}.nii.gz"
            echo "${ROI} warp completed"
    done
done
```

It generates `varname` such as `ROI1_LEFT` using the loop variables `a` and `b` then accesses `$ROI1_LEFT` via `${varname}`.

Comment: I think I was unclear in my question and have updated it. This is close to what I am trying to get but I don't think works for my data

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over left right. The following code:

```
for a in Right_hemi Left_hemi; do
    for b in ROI1 ROI2 ROI3; do
        for direction in LEFT RIGHT; do
             echo "${a}_${b}_\${${b}_${direction}}_*.gz"
        done
    done
done | head -n 3
```

outputs:

```
Right_hemi_ROI1_${ROI1_LEFT}_*.gz
Right_hemi_ROI1_${ROI1_RIGHT}_*.gz
Right_hemi_ROI2_${ROI2_LEFT}_*.gz
```

Comment: I can't mix left and right hemi with left and right ROIs, sorry if that wasn't clear